# Xcode memory increase with UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, uiwebview

[image]

I create a UIWebView thats content a image of a board, when the users change de View and came back again the memory increase, and again and again I try with `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` but no resolve the problem I put

```
IBOutlet  UIWebView __weak *tablero;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *tablero;
```

in the .h file

I desperate for that.

How I clean the memory?

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating request for your webview use

```
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
```

So it doesn't save cache data.

Hope it helps.